# Подключить и вызвать функцию из файла .js

Tags: javascript

В консоль выводит

> функция is not defined

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Function</title>
    <script src="js/function.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <button type="submit" onclick="check()">Check value</button>
</body>
</html>
//Файл function.js
function check(){
    var value=prompt("Please enter the value:", 0);
    var message= (value > 0) ? "1": (value <0) ? "-1": (value==0) ? "0";
    alert(message);
}
```

Подскажите, в чем проблема?

Comment: А путь к файлу точно такой? Может все же косяк в пути? Можно попробовать `./js/function.js`

Comment: не не , гуглил, менял уже все работает..но мучает вопрос почему в консоле пишет что ф-я не определена..ведь ошибка была синтаксическая

Comment: @andrey_KU, добавь в ответ почему не работает.

Comment: @bukashka101 емммм в смысле?..я тут 1 раз и немного не шарю как закрывать тему и тд, подскажи..и зачем добавлять в ответ почему не работает?

Comment: @andrey_KU, пусть Влад уже ответил, но на будущее: если Вы задали вопрос и узнали ответ, Вам нужно ответить на собственный вопрос, а не закрывать его. Другие люди, которые столкнутся с этой проблемой, могут найти здесь ответ. P.S. Ну и Вы репутацию поднимите :))).

Comment: @bukashka101 понял)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас данное предложение синтаксически некорректно

```
var message= (value > 0) ? "1": (value <0) ? "-1": (value==0) ? "0";
```

Попробуйте его исправить следующим образом

```
var message= (value > 0) ? "1": ( (value <0) ? "-1": "0" );
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо, дело в том что нашел статейку https://learn.javascript.ru/ifelse#несколько-операторов и делал оп примеру, но видать не получилось..спасибо еще раз за помощь) Могли бы вы посоветовать книгу по JS для начинающего?

Comment: @user194480 Дело в том, что я сам не знаю JS.:) Просто у меня дурная привычка - отвечать на все вопросы.:) На счет книги могу посоветовать книгу на английском языке, но, думаю, она переведена уже на русский: "PROFESSIONAL JAVASCRIPT® FOR WEB DEVELOPERS" Nicholas C. Zakas

Comment: @user194480 Вообще, по JS можно читать все подряд, что попадет в руки.:)

Comment: Спасибо большое)хорошая у вас привычка- отвечать на все вопросы)

Comment: @andrey_KU Данная проблема, фактически, не имеет отношения к JS. Она связана с тернарным оператором, синтаксис которого одинаков в любом языке, где он присутствует.